# Kotlin custom Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I am new to kotlin, On my application I want to create a custom dialog. I want to show a common dialog. when I call my Dialog,

```
 InfoMessageDialog(activity, "Test Title", "Test desctiption of the dialog.").show();
```

I am getting an error like,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bmates.testApp, PID: 4350
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
    at com.bmates.testApp.Dialogs.InfoMessageDialog.onCreate(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:413)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:308)
    at com.bmates.testApp.Fragments.HomeFragment.writeReviewClick$app_debug(HomeFragment.kt:143)
    at com.bmates.testApp.Fragments.HomeFragment_ViewBinding$3.doClick(HomeFragment_ViewBinding.java:61)
    at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6320)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25087)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
```

Here is my kotlin code,

```
class InfoMessageDialog(context: Context, private var title : String, private var message : String)  : Dialog(context) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.info_dialog)
        window!!.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)

        var txtTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTitle)
        var txtMessage  = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtMessage)
        var btnOK  = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOK)

        txtTitle.setText(title)
        txtMessage.setText(message)

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default parameters in `Kotlin` are non-null. If your parameter could be null then you should add `?` to it's type.

As per your exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState

`savedInstanceState` is null. Use following to correct it.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    ...
```